# Conforming to a protocol which conforms to NSObjectProtocol, without subclassing from NSObject?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, protocols, nsobject

I have a class which has no reason to subclass from NSObject, except that it now wishes to respond to a protocol. But I get the error:

> does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'

I don't wish to subclass from NSObject, and thus have to include all of its init methods in my class and all of its subclasses, just so I can respond to this protocol. Is there a way around it?

Comment: why does it need to conform to `NSObjectProtocol`?

Answer (score 0):

As you've deduced, the protocol you're attempting to conform to descends from `NSObjectProtocol`. Unfortunately, you're basically stuck inheriting from `NSObject`. Correctly adopting `NSObjectProtocol` yourself would be incredibly difficult in a pure Swift class and in doing so you would introduce all of the same issues you'd run into by just subclassing from `NSObject`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import Foundation

class A: NSObject {

}

func f(value: NSObjectProtocol) {

}
let a: A = A()
f(a)
```

So, it is not necessary to 'include' (implement) something to 'respond' to the NSObjectProtocol. The question you have to answer is "Why does it need to conform to NSObjectProtocol?" The answer is somewhere else in you code. Most probably it is because you use some 'ObjectiveC functionality'

Comment: The protocol @Andrew is attempting to conform to descends from `NSObjectProtocol`, and so it inherits its requirements.

Comment: so, the simplest way is subclass NSObject and override what he need to be different, isn't it?